# SQL replace dot with comma

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have following code:

```
SELECT cast(Listenpreis*1.19 as decimal(29,2)) as Listenpreis
 FROM [SL_M03KNE].[dbo].[ARKALK]
```

I get this value: 5.59

I try to replace the dot to a komma so i get the Value: 5,59

I try the code:

```
SELECT replace((cast(Listenpreis*1.19 as decimal(29,2)) as Listenpreis),'.','))
 FROM [SL_M03KNE].[dbo].[ARKALK]
```

But something is wrong with the Syntax. Any Ideas?

I found out: if I do a

```
select Artikelnummer,Listenpreis*1.19 as money from [SL_M03KNE].[dbo].[ARKALK]
```

i get: 5,59

If i do a

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select Artikelnummer,Listenpreis*1.19 as money from [SL_M03KNE].[dbo].[ARKALK]" queryout "D:\shop\xml\Artikelpreise_ohne.csv" -E -c -T -x
```

the bcp do a conversion from the komma to dot. How can i fixed this?

Answer (score 19):

Your `as Listenpreis` aliasing is in the wrong place. It needs to be the last thing. Also the  `'.','` part.

```
SELECT REPLACE(CAST(Listenpreis*1.19 AS DECIMAL(29,2)) ,'.',',')  AS Listenpreis
 FROM [SL_M03KNE].[dbo].[ARKALK]
```

**[SQLFiddle DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c1f7a/1)**

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
select replace(cast(Listenpreis*1.19 as decimal(29,2)),'.',',') as Listenpreis
 from [SL_M03KNE].[dbo].[ARKALK]
```

It does sound like you're compensating for cultural settings, have a look at the `COLLATE` statement.

Comment: I try your Code but i was always error : Syntax error near by "as". I also have a look to Collate but i cannot find the correct Syntax to..

Answer (score 3):

You're missing a comma and an apostrophe (you have `'.','` and you need `'.',','`), try:

```
SELECT 
    REPLACE(CAST(Listenpreis*1.19 as decimal(29,2)), '.', ',')  as Listenpreis
FROM [SL_M03KNE].[dbo].[ARKALK]
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this problem too and to me, the fuction that works is:

CAST(replace_this_with_number_or_column_you_want_to_convert) AS float)

Is that helpful to you too?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell 'bcp "select Artikelnummer, REPLACE(CAST( Listenpreis*1.19 AS VARCHAR),''.'','','') as money from [SL_M03KNE].[dbo].[ARKALK]" queryout "D:\shop\xml\Artikelpreise_ohne.csv" -E -c -T -x'
```