# data factory copy data mssql to postgresql decimal numeric data conversion error

Tags: sql, postgresql, azure, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to migrate data from mssql database to postgresql database using data factory.

But I get an error in a decimal / numeric field. How can I solve this?

```
Error:
Error code
2200
Troubleshooting guide
Failure type
User configuration issue
Details

**'Type=Npgsql.PostgresException,Message=22P02: invalid input syntax for type numeric: "0,833",Source=Npgsql,'**
```

[Azure Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RKvko.png)

Comment: Replace the comma with a period.

Comment: @GordonLinoff
https://stackoverflow.com/a/18252649/15235070
like here ?, when I insert like this, 0.833 => 833 how can I solve it?

Comment: @GordonLinoff https://prnt.sc/zzdy9n

Comment: @OzgurSARIOGLAN what's the source data type? If it's decimal / numeric data type a nd there's a data like '0,833', must be error.

Comment: Source table mssql numeric(38, 6) => target table postgresql numeric mssql data 0.8333

Answer (score 0):

I have one question, what's the source data type? If it's decimal / numeric data type a nd there's a data like '0,833', must be error.

So I assume it's a string data in source and the destination data type is numeric in PostgreSQL.

Since your source is MSSQL, you could just use a `Replace()` function to convert the '0,833' to '0.833':

```
select a, replace(a,',','.') convert_a, test.b from test
```

[image]

Put the query in Source query option:
[image]

**Update:**

Another way, you could use Data Flow Derived column expression to change the data: `replace(a, ',', '.')`:

[image]

[image]

Please set the data type to string in Source projection. Or convert it to string data first: `replace(toString(a), ',', '.')`.

HTH.

Comment: Source table mssql numeric(38, 6) => target table postgresql numeric

Comment: when i apply your solution 0.833 in the source table is inserted to the target table as 833 0 disappears

Comment: @OzgurSARIOGLAN, That's a little strange, please try data flow: derived columns. Please see my update.

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.